# Problem of displaying Russian texts in a tool. (UTF8)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, utf-8, localization

since yesterday I have a problem with displaying Russian texts in one of my tools.

I have the following code in use, which shows the names of items:

```
public static string LocalizedName(LocalizedNames localizedNames, string currentLanguage = null, string alternativeName = "NO_ITEM_NAME")
    {
        if (localizedNames == null)
            return alternativeName;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLanguage))
            currentLanguage = LanguageController.CurrentCultureInfo.TextInfo.CultureName.ToUpper();

        switch (FrequentlyValues.GameLanguages.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Value, currentLanguage, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Key)
        {
            case GameLanguage.UnitedStates:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.EnUs ?? alternativeName));
            case GameLanguage.Germany:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.DeDe ?? alternativeName));
            case GameLanguage.Russia:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.RuRu ?? alternativeName));
            case GameLanguage.Poland:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.PlPl ?? alternativeName));
            case GameLanguage.Brazil:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.PtBr ?? alternativeName));
            case GameLanguage.France:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.FrFr ?? alternativeName));
            case GameLanguage.Spain:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.EsEs ?? alternativeName));
            case GameLanguage.Chinese:
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(localizedNames.ZhCn ?? alternativeName));
            default:
                return alternativeName;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Here is a link to the tool, to test it: https://github.com/Triky313/AlbionOnline-StatisticsAnalysis

For me all languages are displayed correctly (Germany), but other people in Russia only see error texts.

EDIT:
Here a part of the item list file:

```
` "LocalizedNames": {
"EN-US": "Hideout Construction Kit",
"DE-DE": "Unterschlupf-Baukasten",
"FR-FR": "Kit de construction de repaire",
"RU-RU": "ÐÐ°Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð¿Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾Ð¹ÐºÐ¸ ÑƒÐ±ÐµÐ¶Ð¸Ñ‰Ð°",
"PL-PL": "Zestaw do budowy KryjÃ³wki",
"ES-ES": "Kit de construcciÃ³n de Escondites",
"PT-BR": "Kit de ConstruÃ§Ã£o de Esconderijo",
"ZH-CN": "è—èº«åœ°å ¡å»ºç­‘å·¥å…·åŒ…",
"KO-KR": "ì€ì‹ ì²˜ ê±´ì„¤í‚¤íŠ¸" }, `
```

The file will be downloaded from this url:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/broderickhyman/ao-bin-dumps/master/formatted/items.json

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Since in some elements the Russian text is displayed without problems, it is seems the problem in the control that does not display text correctly.

Comment: You should get sources of this package and look inside, how the column **Имя** is implemented.

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(…))` doesn’t make any sense as it means you have an UTF-16 Unicode string (because .NET stores it’s strings in UTF-16), which should be converted to the computers ANSI encoding (that’s what Encoding.Default is) bytes, which should then be decoded as UTF-8. This is just can’t work or rather will only work for the common subset of UTF-8 and your ANSI encoding which are the lower 128 code-points consisting of English letters and numbers. So it’s no wonder that Russian characters will produce garbled output - the same with Chinese.

Comment: The root of these issues that `LocalizedNames` was already populated in a wrong way. You need to provide the proper encoding for each language from the very source where you originally get these strings from. So please show, where you actually detach the strings you put into LocalizedNames.

Comment: Edited the post and added the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is taking string encoded by .NET as UTF-16, converting these to your computer's ANSI encoding (= Encoding.Default) bytes and then decode it as UTF-8. This roundtrip will only yield valid results for the common subset of UTF-8 and your ANSI encoding which are the lower 128 code-points consisting of English letters and numbers. Everything outside of that like Russian, Chinese, Korean, and so on will become garbled.

Your source is JSON file stored as UTF-8.

However in your code you use [WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync) which uses [WebClient.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.encoding) to decide how to convert the downloaded stream to a string. The documentation writes that it defaults to `Encoding.Default` which is generally bad as this depends on how your computer is configured. On a computer with a German locale `Encoding.Default` is Windows-1252/ISO-8859-15, on an English locale its ISO-8859-1, on a Russian computer its probably KOI8R, and so on. This means that code that uses `Encoding.Default` is not portable and even the [documentation warns not to use it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default).

To solve this set `WebClient.Encoding` to `Encoding.UTF8`. Or better: use HttpClient instead as WebClient is deprecated for almost 10 years now.

Afterwards remove all instances of Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(...)) as these are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was elsewhere. The file was saved in UTF8 and not by default.

```
File.WriteAllText($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}{Settings.Default.ItemListFileName}", itemsString, Encoding.Default);
```

It was before **Encoding.UTF8**.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Please see my answer why `Encoding.Default` should never be used and why even Microsoft's own docu warns not to use it.

Comment: @ckuri: Totally overlooked, sorry.
Thanks for the good solution, I'll adjust and change the days.

Thank you.